# Replace value in single statement and implement using apply()

Tags: r

I have a very specific assignment and I keep going in circles. I have to use a single statement to convert 1/2 2/1 3/4 4/3. I also tried `replace` but I can only get it to replace set array positions. I know there's a simple, obvious answer to this, as a single statement, without it looking awful.

```
rearrange <- function(){
  z <- ifelse(1 == 1, 2,
      ifelse(2 == 2, 1,
            ifelse(3 == 3, 4,
                  ifelse(4 == 4, 3,NA))))
}

win <- function(x){
  print(x)
  y <- apply(x,1,rearrange)
  print(y)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::recode` :

```
x[] <- dplyr::recode(x, `1` = 2, `2` = 1, `3` = 4, `4` = 3, .default = NA_real_)
x

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4    2
#[2,]    1    3    1
#[3,]    1    3   NA
```

---

Moreover, you don't need to apply `rearrange` function row-wise using `apply`. Change the function to :

```
rearrange <- function(z){
   ifelse(z == 1, 2,
            ifelse(z == 2, 1,
                  ifelse(z == 3, 4,
                        ifelse(z == 4, 3,NA))))
}
```

and pass the matrix directly to `rearrange`.

```
rearrange(x)
```

---

If there is some dependency to use this in `apply` we can use `rearrange` function from above :

```
solution3 <- function(x){
   cat('+++++Solution 3 (Original)+++++\n')
   print(x)
   cat('+++++Solution 3 (Solution)+++++\n')
   y <- apply(x,2,rearrange)
   #Or apply rowwise with margin = 1
   #y <- t(apply(x,1,rearrange))
   print(y)
}


#+++++Solution 3 (Original)+++++
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    1
#[2,]    2    4    2
#[3,]    2    4    5
#+++++Solution 3 (Solution)+++++
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4    2
#[2,]    1    3    1
#[3,]    1    3   NA
```

Comment: It would be much easy to skip apply but I have to use it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I actually tried this but applied to row. Why is the `apply` code different for column and row?

Comment: Actually it works the same way for both row and column but for row it returns a transposed result. You need to transpose it back to get the desired order. `y <- t(apply(x,1,rearrange))` I have included that as a comment.